# Specify connection on launch for Microsoft Remote Desktop client

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft

I'd like to be able to connect to a specific remote desktop when I start Microsoft's RDT client.  I'm running the latest RDT 8.0.15 client on Yosemite.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by launching from an .rdp file:
* Create the Desktop bookmark in the app
* Export the Desktop as an .rdp file to e.g. your Mac Desktop
* Double-click to start the app and connect to the Desktop.

AFAIK, there's no way to configure the app to launch a desktop at start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can no longer do that. It was possible on older versions but recent versions insist on you choosing from the list.

You used to be able to store 'bookmarks' & launch those directly.